# Creating page and post specific ACF Gutenberg blocks

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, wordpress-gutenberg, acf-gutenberg

I'm creating custom ACF Gutenberg blocks my a site and have successfully managed to register my own blocks. Now, I have a custom post type called `Blog`. I do not want `blog` to show all my ACF Gutenberg blocks, I want to create a separate batch for custom post type use only. I have enabled `show_in_rest`, but even the default Gutenberg blogs do not show for me?

Here is my approach:

**1. Registering the post type (*theme/functions.php*)**

```html
<?php
register_post_type('Blog', theme_build_post_args('Blog', 'Blog', 'Blog', array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-edit',
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'editor',
        'title',
        'author',
        'revisions',
        'excerpt',
        'thumbnail'
    ) ,
)));

?>
```

**2. Registering the ACF Gutenberg blocks for pages (*theme/inc/acf-blocks/blocks.php*)**

Here are the blocks that I've registered for use on pages (not on the `blog` post type):

```html
<?php
$hero = array(
    'name' => 'hero',
    'title' => __('Hero') ,
    'description' => __('') ,
    'render_callback' => 'block_render',
    'category' => 'formatting',
    'icon' => 'admin-comments',
    'keywords' => array(
        'hero'
    ) ,
);

$blocks = [$hero];

return $blocks;

?>
```

3. **Registering the ACF Gutenberg blocks for blog post type (*theme/inc/acf-blocks/blog-blocks.php*)**

```html
<?php
$blog_hero = array(
    'name' => 'blog_hero',
    'title' => __('Blog hero') ,
    'description' => __('') ,
    'render_callback' => 'block_render',
    'category' => 'formatting',
    'icon' => 'admin-comments',
    'keywords' => array(
        'hero',
        'blog'
    ) ,
);

$blog_blocks = [$blog_hero];

return $blog_blocks;

?>
```

4. **Register all blocks (*theme/inc/acf-blocks/functions.php*)**

```html
<?php

/*
* loop though array and register each block type
*/

function block_acf_init(){
  $path = get_template_directory().'/inc/acf-blocks/blocks.php';
  $blocks = require($path);
  foreach($blocks as $block) {
    acf_register_block_type($block);
  }
}

function blog_acf_init(){
  $path = get_template_directory().'/inc/acf-blocks/blog-blocks.php';
  $blog_blocks = require($path);
  foreach($blog_blocks as $blog_block) {
    acf_register_block_type($blog_block);
  }
}


// Check if function exists, and hook into setup
if( function_exists('acf_register_block_type') ) {
  add_action('acf/init', 'block_acf_init');
  add_action('acf/init', 'blog_acf_init');
}


?>
```

**Current results:**

When creating a post on the `blog` custom post type, I do not have the ability to add any blocks, let alone see if `blog_hero` block appears:

[image]

On pages, I can see all my created blocks, however, the `blog hero` block shows on the page side, when I only want it for the custom post type:

[image]

Comment: Does this help: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/metabox/meta-block-4-use-data/  ?

Answer (score 0):

### Probably this way could solve the problem:

Specifying `post_types` param for **Blog Hero** block to **blog**

```
$blog_hero = array(
    'name'            => 'blog_hero',
    'title'           => __( 'Blog hero', 'Context' ),
    'description'     => __( '', 'Context' ),
    'render_callback' => 'block_render',
    'category'        => 'formatting',
    'icon'            => 'admin-comments',
    'keywords'        => array(
        'hero',
        'blog'
    ),
    'post_types'      => array( 'blog' ),
);
```

And analogically specifying all post types except blog for Hero block.

```
$all_post_types        = get_post_types();
$hero_block_post_types = array_diff( $all_post_types, array( 'blog' ) );

$hero = array(
    'name'            => 'hero',
    'title'           => __( 'Hero', 'Domain' ),
    'description'     => __( '', 'Domain' ),
    'render_callback' => 'block_render',
    'category'        => 'formatting',
    'icon'            => 'admin-comments',
    'keywords'        => array(
        'hero'
    ),
    'post_types'      => $hero_block_post_types
);

$blocks = [ $hero ];

return $blocks;
```

**Notice:**

Consider adding Domain for your `__` function.
Good practice to use `__` function with Domain.